# Ignoring a particular attribute using JsonSerializer ContractResolver

Tags: c#, json, json.net, dynamic-programming, nsjsonserialization

I am using JsonSerializer ContractResolver to Ignore empty list . I want add one more condition to ignore
the attribute having a particular name

```
 var serilaizeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = SerializeContractResolver.Instance
                });




protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

            if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) != null)
                    property.ShouldSerialize =
                        instance => (instance?.GetType().GetProperty(property.PropertyName).GetValue(instance) as IEnumerable<object>)?.Count() > 0 && .;
            }
            return property;
        }
```

Is there any way to incorporate a check with the current checks that if attribute name is **CreatedOn** ignore it. Its a type of string value.

Comment: What do you mean by *ignore the attribute having a particular name*?  Do you mean *Ignore a **property** with a specific name*?  Can you share a [mcve] showing the type you want to serialize, and the result you want using your contract resolver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
bool yourAttributeIsOnTheProperty = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CreatedOn), false).Any();
```

Comment: Where I would provide a attribute name?? I want to ignore a particular attribute, in this the attribute name is "CreatedOn"

Comment: Do you want to ignore the property that a specific attribute (named CreatedOn) is located on?

Comment: Yes, correct.I want to incorporate that with my existing checks.

Comment: I changed the answer based on you requirement